# Scikit grid searching the parameters (not hyper parameters)

Tags: python, scikit-learn, regression, minimize, grid-search

Scikit's [GridSearch](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.grid_search.GridSearchCV.html) is perfect when I want to find the best hyper parameters. I want to use the same philosophy to find the best set of parameters for a linear regression, using an objective function across multiple folds. How can I optimize the parameters (literally the betas and intercept) of a linear regression, on multiple folds?

**Use case (simplified):**
I have a dataset that has three years worth of data. I want to define what is the best linear regression that is "ok on all years". If I fit the linear regression the full dataset, I will get the one that reduces the least square error on all data. Effectively I will minimize the error of 
[image]

However, this (`min(error)`)is not my objective. I can get a good result on this objective simply because the classifier did well on year 1 and 2, and that was good enough to compensate for year 3.

What I effectively want to minimize is something along the lines of `min(max(error_year_1, error_year_1, error_year_1))`.

One hacky way about this is to make a function f(b0, b1, b2, year1, year2, year3), which returns the max of the error, and then minimize that function using scipy.

**Actual question:** is there a way to do this in scikit?

Answer (score 0):

It seems to me that scikit only offers direct api access to the [scoring](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/model_evaluation.html) which I believe will only see one fold at a time.

Not very beautiful but I think your best option will be to go over the `grid_scores_` `cv_validation_scores` of the `GridSearchCV` and manually fetch the set of params that minimized the max of the loss function you choose.

Don't think it saves the classifier though, you'll probably have to re-train another logit if you want to use it to make predictions.